# how to setup firefox debugger properly?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, javascript-debugger

I tried the steps for quick setup of firefox debugger at http://firefox-dev.tools/debugger/#quick-setup a few times but had the same problem.

I have pasted all my commands and warning (including error) messages in a gist at the bottom.

I suspect two things may cause the failure of the setting up.

1. when running `curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash -s`, I got warning message saying it is advised to not mix npm with yarn. However, I have not yet found out a way to separate them.
2. when running `yarn`, I got a lot of warning message saying the versions of packages are not matching, a lot of error messages for failing to run commands which I suspect to be the result of `unmet` packages but I can be wrong about it.

or what do you think the problem is?

could you give me some guidance on how to resolve this setting up problem? Thanks

please see the warning and error messages here in the gist.
https://gist.github.com/EmbraceLife/f84993112c5b4a894c30b0a4ba4bb4fc

Answer (score 1):

> it is advised to not mix npm with yarn

...in a single project. If you follow the instructions of cloning a clean repository and running `yarn install` inside, you should be fine.

> I got a lot of warning message saying the versions of packages are not matching

I get these too, so I don't think anything is wrong on your end.

```
warning " > react-redux@5.0.7" has unmet peer dependency "redux@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0-0".
warning "devtools-launchpad > svg-inline-react@3.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0".
warning "devtools-launchpad > url-loader@0.5.9" has unmet peer dependency "file-loader@*".
warning " > eslint-plugin-mozilla@1.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-no-unsanitized@^3.0.0".
warning "devtools-reps > devtools-components > @storybook/react@3.4.8" has unmet peer dependency "babel-core@^6.26.0 || ^7.0.0-0".
warning "devtools-reps > devtools-components > @storybook/react@3.4.8" has unmet peer dependency "babel-runtime@>=6.0.0".
warning " > babel-jest@23.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "babel-core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0-0".
```

> node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.2.4 and node@12.9.1 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)

followed by a large number of build errors, ending with:

```
30 warnings and 14 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
```

...looks like a problem with your [running node12](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27389) (the CI seems to be running [with node10](https://github.com/firefox-devtools/debugger/blob/aa827095d86475f816017ff35d6f9c2e83cf7b9b/.circleci/config.yml#L19)) but I'm not even sure lack of fsevents is fatal...

> Listening for WS on localhost:8116, all traffic is proxied to localhost:6080
>
> TCP connection failed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6080

These messages in your output are expected - you're supposed to run a controlled instance of the browser that listens on port 6080, until you do the "launcher" page tries to connect and fails repeatedly.

Apart from the console messages, is there a problem or does the debugger work?

Comment: I tried again this time, and the only change is to use the command `yarn install` instead of `yarn`. However the result is the same. 

As you expected, when I launched the page, in my terminal it repeated the following messages

Comment: The debugger does not work. You see the image here https://photos.app.goo.gl/LpNvqJ1KeZLZBMLx7

Comment: The screenshot indicates you've already started the child Nightly session - is that correct? Did you do so via a button in the launcher or [manually](http://firefox-dev.tools/debugger/docs/getting-setup.html#starting-firefox-nightly)? Did you open a tab with a page to debug, as the message says? Did you try downgrading to node10 LTS?

Comment: I don't think it would work, but thanks Nickolay, I will try to follow this guide here. https://gist.github.com/jaril/0a4fdc1949f97d90b2c73c5523939678